# Using mt2pro with times: \PARENS{.....} vs \left(....\right)

Tags: brackets, fractions, times, mtpro

If I use the command `\PARENS{.....}` with `mtpro2` (green color into the figure in attachment) for to obtain a perfect brace curve (round bracket) I have **1 (one) problem**:
the first and the second line of the fractions of the first equal are aligned and they have the same thick (you can see the two red rectangles).

But the line of the third fraction (green color) is not perfectly aligned with the previous fractions (infact two are below and the third is above) and the thick is different of the previous red fractions. To create a correct fraction with the two parens at the same distance with the command `\PARENS{.....}`, using the package `mtpro2`, I have added a `matrix`, the command `\phantom{Z}` and `\hspace{-.3cm}` (you can see the green color).

Is there a different idea or solution to obtain of the perfect aligned fractions, with the same thick and perfect PARENS `(...)` (round brackets) so as when I use the command `\left(....\right)`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} 
\usepackage{classico}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\overline F =\frac{d\overline p}{dt}&=\\
&=\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{u^2}{c^2}}}\frac{d\overline u}{dt}+m\overline u\PARENS{\begin{matrix}\phantom{Z}&\\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{u^2}{c^2}}} \hspace{-.3cm}\end{matrix}}=\\
&=\frac{m}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{u^2}{c^2}}}\,\overline a +\frac{\overline u}{c^2}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{u^2}{c^2}}}\right)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Good question with a probably disappointing answer: the code for `\PARENS` is a big collection of low level hacks and fixing that issue would mean add some more after a few days' work (assuming a solution can be found in a finite amount of time).

Comment: Thanks a lot, always, for your comments. I never imagined that there were such problems.

Comment: To the downvoter: If you do not explain/comment why the question is wrong, the downvote itself is meaningless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thickness just appears to be different (probably due to how each pixel is rendered on screen). It should be fine if you print them out.

*Solution 2 is added (2019/04/04), which should be preferred than solution 1.*

## Solution 1: Manipulate content’s height or depth

**Disadvantages (added 2019/04/04)**: There are several disadvantages with this approach, e.g.,

1. The content is set in `\displaystyle` explicitly, but this is done by the original `\PARENS` anyway.
2. All spaces (math skips) in the content are “frozen”, so it cannot participate in stretching or shrinking of the line.
3. If you have a long and tall formula which needs to be split into two lines while being delimitered, then you have to manually insert an appropriate `\vphantom` to guarantee the same size of the delimiters. (Note: This solution deals with `\PARENS` only, but can be easily extended to cover `\LEFTRIGHT`, where the described problem may occur)
4. It requests a new box register.

Sounds familiar? Almost all these disadvantages are identical to the usage of “automatic sizing” in LaTeX, which is why I offer a second “manual sizing” solution.

The `\PARENS` command puts its content in a `\vcenter`, thus, it will ignore the positioning of the content’s baseline and the surrounding baseline. We can use some low-level box tricks to make the content symmetric with respect to the math axis, so that the two baselines are the same. The new command is called `\symmPARENS` (for the lack of a better name… feel free to change it to, say, `\myPARENS`). (Notice that I also changed `\overline` to `\wbar` to get better-looking accent. BTW, shouldn’t the `u` be `v` for velocity?)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools} % Load this early
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{newtxtext} % This is better :)
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}

% Low-level hacks:
\makeatletter
\newsavebox\mtp@symm@box % The box to be made symmetric
% Command that adjusts the box:
\newcommand*\mtp@adjust@box[1]{%
  \dimen@\dp#1%
    \advance\dimen@\fontdimen22\textfont\tw@ % \dimen@ is the length from the math axis to the bottom
  \dimen@ii\ht#1%
    \advance\dimen@ii-\fontdimen22\textfont\tw@ % \dimen@ii is the length from the math axis to the top
  \ifdim\dimen@>\dimen@ii % Box too deep
    \advance\dimen@\fontdimen22\textfont\tw@
      \ht#1\dimen@ % Make box higher
  \else % Box too high
    \advance\dimen@ii-\fontdimen22\textfont\tw@
      \dp#1\dimen@ii % Make box deeper
  \fi
}
% User level command:
\newcommand*\symmPARENS[1]{%
  \setbox\mtp@symm@box\hbox{$\m@th\displaystyle#1$}% Put content in a box
  \mtp@adjust@box\mtp@symm@box % Adjust the content box so baselines align
  \PARENS{\copy\mtp@symm@box}% Send the box back to \PARENS
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
With \verb|\PARENS|, not so good:
\begin{equation}
\wbar{F} = \frac{d \wbar{p}}{dt}
  = \frac{m}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{u^2}{c^2}}} \frac{d \wbar{u}}{dt}
      + m \wbar{u} \PARENS{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{u^2}{c^2}}}}
\end{equation}
With \verb|\symmPARENS|, centered, but not aesthetically pleasing:
\begin{equation}
\wbar{F} = \frac{d \wbar{p}}{dt}
  = \frac{m}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{u^2}{c^2}}} \frac{d \wbar{u}}{dt}
      + m \wbar{u} \symmPARENS{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{u^2}{c^2}}}}
\end{equation}
Why not:
\begin{equation}
\wbar{F} = \frac{d \wbar{p}}{dt}
  = \gamma m \frac{d \wbar{u}}{dt}
      + \gamma m \wbar{u},
 \quad \text{where } \gamma = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{u^2}{c^2}}}
\end{equation}
Please don't abuse \verb|\symmPARENS|:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} f(\xi) = \frac{1}{2} \symmPARENS{\frac{\displaystyle\int_a^b f(x) \, dx}{b-a}}
\text{ versus }
\frac{1}{2} f(\xi) = \frac{1}{2} \symmPARENS{\frac{1}{b-a} \displaystyle\int_a^b f(x) \, dx}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: parens]

Seriously, though, I would just write Eq. (3) instead.

## Solution 2: Create `\biggg`-variants to access individual delimiter (2019/04/04)

**Disadvantages**: None. (Joking) This does not work well in footnotes or in titles (who would write huge formula in these places anyway?), but neither is `\PARENS`, `\LEFTRIGHT` or solution 1. This is because extra-large symbol fonts are loaded at *fixed size*, so there is nothing much we can do.

The idea is based on `\def\biggg{\bBigg@{3}}`, `\def\Biggg{\bBigg@{3.5}}`, etc. But we need something that is capable to switch font.

Studying the 4 extensible fonts of `mtpro2`: `mt2exa`, `mt2exe`, `mt2exf` and `mt2exg`, I find that parentheses, braces, angle brackets and slashes are displayed at the following sizes:

```
| mt2exa |  1.2em |  1.8em |  2.4em |  3.0em |
| mt2exe |  3.6em |  4.2em |  4.8em |  5.4em |  6.0em |  6.6em |  7.2em (N/A) |
| mt2exf |  7.2em |  8.4em |  9.6em | 10.8em | 12.0em | 13.2em | 14.4em (N/A) |
| mt2exg | 14.4em | 16.8em | 19.2em | 21.6em | 24.0em | 26.4em | 28.8em       |
```

The command `\mtp@bBigg@` below takes 3 arguments: `#1` is the font, `#2` is the size relative to `\big@size` and `#3` is the delimiter. There are 2 details:

- If `#3` is any one among `(`, `)`, `<`, `\langle`, `>`, `\rangle`, `/`, `\backslash`, `\{`, `\}`, `\lbrace`, `\rbrace`, `\lcbrace`, `\rcbrace`, then we should use possibly different font. This can be done by `\specdelim@#3`.
- However, if the `straightbraces` or the `morphedbraces` option is used and the delimiter is any one among `\{`, `\}`, `\lbrace`, `\rbrace`, we should switch back to `mt2exa` and use straight pieced-together braces.

To use `\mtp@bBigg@`, you do

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\mtpbiggg{\mtp@bBigg@\MTEXE@{3}}
\newcommand*\mtpBiggg{\mtp@bBigg@\MTEXE@{3.5}}
...
\newcommand*\mtpbigggggg{\mtp@bBigg@\MTEXF@{6}}
\newcommand*\mtpBigggggg{\mtp@bBigg@\MTEXF@{7}}
...
% \MTEXE@ should be followed by  3 ,  3.5 ,  4 ,  4.5 ,  5 ,  5.5
% \MTEXF@ should be followed by  6 ,  7   ,  8 ,  9   , 10 , 11
% \MTEXG@ should be followed by 12 , 14   , 16 , 18   , 20 , 22   , 24
\makeatother
```

BTW, the `\big@size` calculation by either `amsmath` or `mtpro2` is [arguably wrong](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/277), so I also provide a fix.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,xcolor,newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\makeatletter
% Fix \big@size calculation
\addto@hook\every@math@size{%
  \global\big@size6\fontdimen6\textfont\thr@@\relax
  \global\divide\big@size by5\relax}
% \mtp@bBigg@: #1=font, #2=relative size, #3=delimiter
\newcommand*\mtp@bBigg@[3]{\leavevmode@ifvmode
  {\hbox{\specdelim@#3%
    \ifspecdelim@ % Switch font only for special delimiters
      \textfont\thr@@=#1%
      \ifnum
        \ifx#3\{ 1\else\ifx#3\} 1\else
        \ifx#3\lbrace 1\else\ifx#3\rbrace 1\else 0\fi\fi\fi\fi
          =1 % But if the delimiter is any of \{, \}, \lbrace or \rbrace
        \def\@tempa{\delimiter"4266308 }% We compare it with curly \lbrace
        \ifx\lbrace\@tempa\else
          \textfont\thr@@=\MTEXA@ % straight or morphed used, switch back to mt2exa
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
    $\left#3\vcenter to#2\big@size{}\right.\n@space$}}}
% 6 mt2exe sizes:
\newcommand*\mtpbiggg{\mtp@bBigg@\MTEXE@\thr@@}
\newcommand*\mtpBiggg{\mtp@bBigg@\MTEXE@{3.5}}
\newcommand*\mtpbigggg{\mtp@bBigg@\MTEXE@4}
\newcommand*\mtpBigggg{\mtp@bBigg@\MTEXE@{4.5}}
\newcommand*\mtpbiggggg{\mtp@bBigg@\MTEXE@5}
\newcommand*\mtpBiggggg{\mtp@bBigg@\MTEXE@{5.5}}
% 2 mt2exf sizes (you get the idea):
\newcommand*\mtpbigggggg{\mtp@bBigg@\MTEXF@6}
\newcommand*\mtpBigggggg{\mtp@bBigg@\MTEXF@7}
\makeatother

% The corresponding l, m, r version:
\newcommand*\mtpbigggl{\mathopen\mtpbiggg}\newcommand*\mtpbigggm{\mathrel\mtpbiggg}\newcommand*\mtpbigggr{\mathclose\mtpbiggg}
\newcommand*\mtpBigggl{\mathopen\mtpBiggg}\newcommand*\mtpBigggm{\mathrel\mtpBiggg}\newcommand*\mtpBigggr{\mathclose\mtpBiggg}
\newcommand*\mtpbiggggl{\mathopen\mtpbigggg}\newcommand*\mtpbiggggm{\mathrel\mtpbigggg}\newcommand*\mtpbiggggr{\mathclose\mtpbigggg}
\newcommand*\mtpBiggggl{\mathopen\mtpBigggg}\newcommand*\mtpBiggggm{\mathrel\mtpBigggg}\newcommand*\mtpBiggggr{\mathclose\mtpBigggg}
\newcommand*\mtpbigggggl{\mathopen\mtpbiggggg}\newcommand*\mtpbigggggm{\mathrel\mtpbiggggg}\newcommand*\mtpbigggggr{\mathclose\mtpbiggggg}
\newcommand*\mtpBigggggl{\mathopen\mtpBiggggg}\newcommand*\mtpBigggggm{\mathrel\mtpBiggggg}\newcommand*\mtpBigggggr{\mathclose\mtpBiggggg}
\newcommand*\mtpbiggggggl{\mathopen\mtpbigggggg}\newcommand*\mtpbiggggggm{\mathrel\mtpbigggggg}\newcommand*\mtpbiggggggr{\mathclose\mtpbigggggg}
\newcommand*\mtpBiggggggl{\mathopen\mtpBigggggg}\newcommand*\mtpBiggggggm{\mathrel\mtpBigggggg}\newcommand*\mtpBiggggggr{\mathclose\mtpBigggggg}

% Visual check
\newcommand*\redline[1]{\vcenter{\color{red}\hrule height#1em width0.4pt}}
\newcommand*\test[2]{%
  \frac{d \wbar{u}}{dt}%
  #1%
  \bigl#1\redline{1.2}\Bigl#1\redline{1.8}%
  \biggl#1\redline{2.4}\Biggl#1\redline{3.0}%
  \mtpbigggl#1\redline{3.6}\mtpBigggl#1\redline{4.2}%
  \mtpbiggggl#1\redline{4.8}\mtpBiggggl#1\redline{5.4}%
  \mtpbigggggl#1\redline{6.0}\mtpBigggggl#1\redline{6.6}%
  \mtpbiggggggl#1\redline{7.2}\mtpBiggggggl#1\redline{8.4}%
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{u^2}{c^2}}}%
  \times
  \frac{\displaystyle\int\limits_a^b f(x)\,h(x)\,dx + \sum_{i=1}^n y_i w_i}%
       {\int\limits_a^b g(x)\,h(x)\,dx + \sum_{i=1}^n z_i w_i}%
  \mtpBiggggggr#2%
}
\begin{document}
\[ \test()          \]
% Uncomment to do the following tests:
%\[ \test\vert\Vert  \]
%\[ \test\{>         \]
%\[ \test/\backslash \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: manual sizing]

Comment: @egreg A challenge (since a solution is found in a finite amount of time `;-)`): Is there a LaTeX2e way to generate the `\bBigggggg` variants more efficiently for my second solution? I read your recent TUGboat article *TeX.StackExchange cherry picking: expl3* about LaTeX3’s “macro factory”, so it can be done with `expl3`. Curious about a LaTeX2e approach, though.

Comment: I'd like to congratulate you most sincerely. You did great. It's a shame no one voted for your answer anymore. It's excellent for me.